# SQL Server not connecting to specific network

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I can connect without any problem to my Sql Server (network service) at home or anywhere else except at work. Sometimes it gets a spirit of the moment connection and then just disconnects again.

It keeps giving me this error:

```
==========================================================================

Cannot connect to winsqls02.cpt.wa.co.za.

==========================================================================


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried restarting my laptop, pinging the server, changing to another router at work, but nothing seems to work.

Is there maybe a simple reason for this issue, because I can't seem to find any answers on the internet.

Comment: Can anyone else at work connect to the SQL server?  Maybe it's not set up to allow external connections.

Comment: I'm assuming that your work has a firewall. If so, is the SQL port 1433 opened for outbound connection?

Comment: @WEI_DBA The weird thing is that in the morning before everybody is here, it connects perfectly to the server... So it won't be the firewall, as I am able to connect up until everybody else arrives.

Comment: @RickS I can connect from multiple places, just not at work...

Comment: That is odd. It's definitely not a SQL server issue then if you can connect for a period of time.